# display the table data using pagination in zend

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

When i am doing pagination using zend:

I am getting this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/ZendApp/application/controllers/ContsizesController.php on line 17

Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object in /var/www/ZendApp/application/controllers/ContsizesController.php on line 17

//Controller

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM contsize ';
$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);
$page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
$paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
$this->view->paginator=$paginator;
```

The above mentioned code i am using in controller.
Please help me to correct it.Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you.

```
class PathToClass_ClassName extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    /*$_name is zend global for selecting db table*/
    protected $_name = 'contsize';

    public function paginationZend()

    /*$this->select() by default selectingall records from database*/
    $SELECT = $this->SELECT();
    $result = $this->fetchAll($SELECT);
    $page=$this->_getParam('page',1);
    $paginator = Zend_Paginator::factory($result);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage(10);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    $this->view->paginator=$paginator;

}
```

Than you can call your function where you want.